# Font on math.stack chat function

Tags: fonts, times

I wanted to know if anybody recognised the packages used to obtain the font found on the chat of the math stack exchange. I tried `\usepackage{mathptmx}` but the integrals seemed to be a bit off. It looks a bit like the times font but I'm unsure.

Below is an attached screenshot of some of the math that's been typeset on the chat.

> [image: Text]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Kari

Comment: Hi, please can you add a MWE? There are two different math-mode for `z`.

Comment: Oh, I accidentally typed \text{z} in the denominator out of habit when I was typing \text{d} for the differential. That's why it's different. I can't add an MWE because it's a screenshot of the chat area of the math stackexchange.

Comment: I understand. I thought that you had typed. Sorry.

Comment: do you mean someone posted an image to the chat, or do you mean the font used by the mathjax rendering of tex-like markup in the browser? (in the latter case you can ask your browser what font it is)

Comment: It's the latter, @DavidCarlisle. May I ask how I can ask my browser?

Comment: I just visited the chat and mathjax isn't enabled? Do you have a "mathjax everywhere" plugin installed? but on any web page you can go to the developer menu and query the fonts, details depend on the browser, in firefox just click on the text and choose inspect element from the right menu.

Comment: I would guess it would be stix

Comment: There's a link [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html) that allows you to set a bookmark to enable mathjax, @DavidCarlisle. Perhaps that helps?

Comment: note that mathjax specific questions (which this clearly is) are usually considered off topic here

Comment: Ah, I was unaware that those were off-topic. Apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks very much like `newtx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext, newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\[ \oint_C \frac{\mathrm d z}{z} = \oint_C \frac{\mathrm dx + i\mathrm dy}{x + iy}\]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does indeed look like it but when I copy this into a blank document, the integral signs come out looking very different, @Bernard. I've attached a link to a screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/ldpuC

Comment: You seem to have the `upright` version of the integral. Normally, this corresponds to the `upright` option. I used the default. Which version of `newtx` do you have?

Comment: It says `newtxtext.sty 2016/03/27 v1.466`, @Bernard.

Comment: Anyway the problem is with `newtxmath.sty`. Lates `newtx` is 1.514 (2016/11/18). Probably you should update.

Comment: Any idea how I can update to the latest `newtx`, @Bernard? (I'm on a Mac and I recently ran MacTeX's update today from tug)

Comment: With TeX Live Utilities, I suppose. Do you have it installed?

Comment: I checked in the doc: from version 1.5; the default is slanted integrals, which implicitly means that previous versions had upright as default.

Comment: Yep, that's resolved my question. Thanks for the help!
(I'll go ahead and accept your answer!)